# Can COD 3 be played cross-platform between PS3 and PS4?

Tags: ps3, ps4, call-of-duty-black-ops-3

I have a PS3 and want to play with and or against my buddy who has a PS4.  Does this matter having different machines?  It's all the same network, right?

Comment: lol I read this and thought it was about COD3 as in Call of Duty 3 and I was confused as to when it came out for PS4. Guess I'm getting old.

Answer (score 1):

According to this site: http://www.polygon.com/2013/10/30/5047272/sony-ps3-and-ps4-cross-play-is-technically-possible

It should technically be possible since both consoles connects to PSN. It's up to the developers to implement it.

**Bottom line, I don't think this is gonna be possible for PS3 and PS4 COD3. Since users all over the internet are all saying that they both have different servers.**

But that still depends on the game, it might be possible for other games.

Comment: Wouldn't it be all the same to the developers, since people have to buy their game either way? And this doesn't really answer the question of if it's possible or not for Black Ops 3